# read all cases and tell which is first and last comment

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, case

In my Org, I have about 100,000 cases and more than 100,000 case comments. I want to show which case comment is first and last for each case. Is there a way to achieve this using apex batch?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to do this with batch Apex? If you only need to show the first and last comments for a Case when someone views a case, there are likely better or easier options.

Comment: Do the comments need to be statically linked or do you just need to show them when the Case is viewed? Are the comments in Chatter?

Comment: Instead of Running Batch - FIRST COMMENT : This is never gonna change(Except delete situation), you can write TRIGGER on CaseComment (Insert & Delete) - if deleted= First (use some flag variable here to know your first), if insert = then comment will become your Last.

Comment: can we do it without using Batch Apex.Since I had more than 1 lakh case comments

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to view the first and last comments on a given Case when viewing the case, then I'd recommend you accomplish this with a small Visualforce page and controller extension.

As a note, I am assuming that:

- 'first comment' means 'the most recently added comment'
- 'last comment' means 'the oldest comment on the case'

You may have hundreds of thousands of `Cases` and `CaseComments`, but the number of comments on a single Case is likely to be much more manageable.

Making the Visualforce page and the controller extension is pretty basic. If you need examples, I'll direct you to [the docmentation for creating a custom controller extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm)

To get the first and last comments, start by querying for `CaseComments` related to the Case you are viewing. This can be done in the constructor.

```
List<Case> comments = [SELECT Id, CommentBody FROM CaseComments WHERE ParentId = <case id> ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC]
```

From there, the first comment will be the first entry in the list resulting from that query, and the last comment will be the last entry in the list.

You'll need to check that your query returned at least one result. After that, you can store the first and last comments in a pair of controller variables

```
if(comments.size() > 0){
    firstComment = comments.get(0);
    lastComment = comments.get(comments.size() - 1);
}
```

Keep in mind that if you only have one comment on a Case, `firstComment` and `lastComment` will be the same. You may want additional logic to detect this, but that's completely optional.

After that, it's just a matter of writing the Visualforce page. Displaying the first and last comments might look like this

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:outputText label="First Comment" value="{!firstComment.CommentBody}" />
    <apex:outputText label="Last Comment" value="{!lastComment.CommentBody}" />
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Then, modify your Case page layout (or layouts) by adding your Visualforce page somewhere in the layout.